# ajax success переход на другую страницу

Tags: html, ajax

Есть ajax запрос, как сделать, чтобы в случае успеха открывалась другая страница?

Comment: В объекте ajax'а напишите `success` функцию и сделайте там редирект. `success: function(data){ window.location.replace('Redirect_URL') }`

Comment: window.open ="http://..'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.location = 'http://...';
```